# DB2 lock timeout

Tags: db2

We have a WebSphere cluster with four clones.  Identical code runs on each of the clones.  We have Quartz periodically kick off a job that runs the code.

The code tries to update a row in a table so that only one of the clones will be able to successfully update the table, and then that clone will run the rest of the job.  Something like:

```
update <table> set status = 'RUNNING' where job_name = 'JOB1' and status = 'STOPPED'
```

We do not start a transaction when we execute the update statement.

What we see sometimes is that all four clones fail to update the table, and all get a lock timeout error (sql code -913).

We've also tried an alternative where we start a transaction, select to see if the row is marked as running, and if not, then performing an update and committing; and otherwise rolling back.

That had the same problem.

One solution we did not try yet is to modify the select to be a "select for update" although from my googleing, I have doubts as to whether that will help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of DB2?  What's the complete error message?  Are you sure nothing else is touching that table, and there are no triggers (or similar)?  How often do statements run like this - is it possible that a previous transaction is still running?  Running an `UPDATE` like this is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up not being a problem (that's what I get for listening to someone without checking it out myself).

I tested this out in our development environment with two clones.  One of the clones would see the -913 lock timeout error occasionally while the other clone would successfully update the table.  Other than the ugly log message, everything worked as it should.

Usually, however, we would not get the -913 error, but rather a warning indicating that there was no row to update from one of the clones.  Again, this behavior is fine.

So, as we originally thought, and Clockwork-Muse also suggests, using UPDATE statements in this manner to enforce a lock works just fine in DB2.